# upload a file via value of input tag in HTML

Tags: html, file-upload

How can send a file via input like this :

```
  <form action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" value="C:\Users\xxx\Documents\image.jpg"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

If you see above code I want send a file without select handly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify a path like that (or any path for that matter). That would be a security risk and browsers disallow such behavior.